# How to Flag External Types/Methods as Deprecated/Obsolete in .NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net

We're trying to flag usage of external types (like `ConfigurationManager`) at build time.

A custom code analysis dictionary could help [1] but only in scenarios where source is included in the project. Similarly the `Obsolete` attribute works on types included in the project.

I'm not even sure if Code Analysis rules are capable of inspecting method bodies? [2].

Any suggestions on how we can flag usage of external types/methods at build-time?

[1] - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514188.aspx

[2] - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd172127(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 2):

For the folks coming to this question in 2023 and later, there is now a Roslyn analyzer for that.

See [Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BannedApiAnalyzers](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/blob/main/src/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BannedApiAnalyzers/BannedApiAnalyzers.Help.md).

You need to:

1. Reference the analyzer package (using a `Directory.Build.props` or a custom `props` file will allow doing that globally for a solution);

   ```
   <ItemGroup>
       <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BannedApiAnalyzers" Version="3.3.4">
           <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
           <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
       </PackageReference>
   </ItemGroup>
   ```
2. Create a new `BannedSymbols.txt` and include all the banned symbols into it;
3. Include `BannedSymbols.txt` into the same projects as the analyzer;

   ```
   <ItemGroup>
       <AdditionalFiles Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)/BannedSymbols.txt" />
   </ItemGroup>
   ```

E.g. in order to ban `Refit.RestService` type, you'll need to have sth like `T:Refit.RestService;Don't use it`, which will result in a compilation warning in both your IDE, dotnet CLI and CI.

[image]

Comment: Do you know of any tool that given a human-readable C# symbol, will give you that preposterous "Documentation Comment ID string" for that symbol?

Comment: Do you know of any way to configure those `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BannedApiAnalyzers` to display my error message and only my error message, without their annoyingly presumptuous and limiting part which reads "The symbol '{}' is banned in this project: " ?

Comment: @MikeNakis I don't know such a tool. However, rules are simple and all the possible symbols are covered by the link I've provided. More detailed rules are here https://github.com/dotnet/csharpstandard/blob/standard-v6/standard/documentation-comments.md#d42-id-string-format, however not everything is supported. E.g. it wasn't possible to ban the whole namespace in the latest non prerelease version.

Comment: As to the custom error messages with no predefined part, I don't think that is possible. Might only suggest creating a github issue.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that is to create a custom FxCop rule, checking fields during code analysis phase with something like this:

```
internal sealed class SampleRule : BaseIntrospectionRule
{

    public override ProblemCollection Check(Member member)
    {
        const string typeName = "System.DateTime";
        var field = member as Field;
        if (field == null || field.Type.FullName != typeName)
            return null;
        return new ProblemCollection 
        { 
            new Problem(new Resolution(field.Name.Name, "Type {0} is obsolete", typeName)) 
        };
    }
}
```

I'd recommend having a look at [this tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codeanalysis/archive/2010/03/26/how-to-write-custom-static-code-analysis-rules-and-integrate-them-into-visual-studio-2010.aspx).